# External volume (WB elements 2TB) does not mount on mac (exFat)

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, mount, exfat

I have an WD Elements 2TB external harddrive which is unable to mount on my Mac. It is formatted exFat and is half full.

When I go into disk utility it is greyed out. Clicking the mount button doesnt resolve anything. When running "first aid" the following message appears:

[image]

Ok, now maybe something serious is wrong. But when checking on a windows machine it *does* appear and all my files are accessible.

What can I do? If it has to I can resort to removing all the files via a windows machine and reformatting the drive. However, it does involve buying a new external drive just to do that. So that would be my last resort.. any ideas?

Comment: you could try mounting the drive with a 3rd party app like Mountain.  I've had problems in the past of not being able to mount a drive.  Often Mountain would work.

Comment: Mountain can be downloaded [here](https://appgineers.de/mountain/). Excellent app. Just gave it a try and I like it. _Disclaimer:_ No financial or other ties to appgineers.de.

Comment: Ok, great. I’ll try that later on and update based on the results

Comment: I tried Mountain to mount the disk. No luck. It only resolved ejecting (as it wasn't shown in disk utility anymore) however, mounting didn't work. I'll guess I'll buy a new one.